# Phirehose hangs?

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-streaming-api

I'm trying to use Phirehose to get Twitter tweets for a particular keyword but it always seems to hang when I launch the page on my site. There are two examples, I have:

1) using [140dev's work](http://140dev.com/free-twitter-api-source-code-library/) (with a good MySQL dB setup):
http://www.rioleo.org/projecthaiti/streamer/db/get_tweets.php

2) using Phirehose only
http://www.rioleo.org/projecthaiti/stream/example/sample.php

I've noticed that I get output sometimes when I do

```
$sc = new SampleConsumer('username', 'pass', Phirehose::METHOD_SAMPLE);
$sc->consume();
```

but it hangs unceremoniously when I do:

```
$sc = new SampleConsumer('username', 'pass', Phirehose::METHOD_FILTER);
$sc->setTrack(array('keyword'));
$sc->consume();
```

right now `enqueueStatus($status)` just echoes the `$status`.

I realize the whole point of Phirehose is to have it run for a certain amount of time, collect tweets and then play around with them, but I'm not sure I understand how the code I have should at least get me partially there. An enlightenment would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't really understand your question. You say you have tried the 140dev code. Did it work? Did data flow into the database? Did you get any error messages? What exactly happened, and what about that was confusing?

Comment: Well it doesn't work in the sense that I can't get anything to load. Is there something I'm missing? I feel like their documentation of "this script has to run in the background" is an indication that I can't actually run it on a conventional web server?

Comment: The question makes it look like a thread about suicides. `Fire-hose hangs`

Answer (score 0):

There are erros in the Phirehose code and a few blocking calls. Look at these defect reports
http://code.google.com/p/phirehose/issues/list

This issue in particular should describe how to partially fix the code:
http://code.google.com/p/phirehose/issues/detail?id=4

I've also found its good to remove the feof() call from the consume while loop as this is a blocking call in PHP and can cause hangs in my experience.

Comment: Phirehose is designed to be run from the terminal, not on a webserver.